# Regex to allow letters, one space between words and a total length of 50

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to build a regular expression with the following conditions:

- Only letters
- One space between words (no more than one space)
- Maximum length 50

And this is what I have done so far:

```
^(([A-Za-z]+( [A-Za-z])+){1,50})$
```

This allows me to validate the spaces between words and only letters conditions but it is not working for the length and it's not working for words without spaces, example:`hello`. Can someone help me with this?

Example:

What I need:
Regex that allows sentences (with max length 50) like this:

```
Hello this is an example
Hello
a b c
```

Comment: Easier to read would to be enforce the length requirement separately. First do `if (value.Length > 50) return false;`, and then do the content check. (Note also that you don't seem to be clear about whether an empty string is legal or not. The description says yes, but your proposed regular expression says no.)

Comment: Also, you are not detecting accented letters as letters. Consider using \p{L} instead of [A-Za-z].

Comment: Thanks, I made the change and it works. So the final regex that now i have is this: `^(?!.*?\s{2})[\p{L} ]{1,50}$`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
^\b(?!.*?\s{2})[A-Za-z ]{1,50}\b$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pY9hG2/18)

`[A-Za-z ]{1,50}` will check for the characters and length, while the negative lookahead `(?!.*?\s{2})` will check for the spaces condition. (\b) to disallow white space at ends.

Comment: Is the second '?' in the lookahead required?

Comment: @glibdud No, but it avoids the need to backtrack and the regex *should* be faster with it.